# How to close underlying socket after response is sent?

Tags: node.js, http, server

I have simple server example. In my server I have to close the underlying `NET` socket after the response is sent to the client. I tried this.

```
var counter = 0;

app.post("/enddev", (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST TO ", req.route.path);

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(++counter);
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    res.write("upd\r\n");
    res.end();
  }, 1000);

  res.on("finish", () => {
    console.log("Res socket: ", res.socket);
  });
});


server.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(
    "New connection",
    "Address: " + socket.address().address,
    "Port: " + socket.address().port
  );

  socket.on("timeout", () => {
    console.log("socket timeout");
    socket.end();
  });

  socket.on("error", err => {
    console.log("Socket error: ", err);
  });

  socket.on("close", hadError => {
    console.log(
      hadError
        ? "Socket closed due to ERROR during transmission"
        : "Socket closed"
    );
  });
});
```

When I run this program I observe that the socket is closed about 5 seconds after request is issued. Socket do not close upon `res.end()` but 5 seconds later.

This is console snapshot of program running:

[image]

I want to close the socket immediately after `res.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to check if socket connection already exists or not. If it does not then you should then create a connection:

Client:

```
if (!this.socket) {
    this.socket= io("URL", { secure: true });
}
```

Server:

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const userId = socket.userId;
        userOperation.logout(dbConnection, userId);
});
```